# Is it possible to set these IIS7 settings in a web.config file?

Tags: iis-7, configuration, web.config, bindings

with my IIS7 site, i manually set the bindings for my site.

Is it possible to set these bindings in the (local) web.config file? Not a machine or app config file ... but the web.config file?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The system.webServer settings are supposed to be stored in applicationhost.config file only. web.config can have site specific changes or modification but Web site specific configuration are always stored in applicationhost.config.  are  element and are in turn  element.

From IIS 7 Resource Kit:

> ApplicationHost.config contains
>   configuration sections and settings
>   that only make sense globally on the
>   server. For example, it contains site,
>   application, and virtual directory
>   definitions in the  section and
>   the application pool definitions for
>   the  section.

Answer (score 0):

This information is stored in the application.config file, check out http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application